# Contact won't ring through vibrate mode when set as "Allow during Do not disturb"

Tags: do-not-disturb

As the title says. I have a contact who will call with 1 of 24 different phone numbers. I have set that contact as Allow during Do not disturb in the sound and vibrate settings. When they call it does not ring through but instead vibrates only.

I am on a Samsung S22 updated to Android 13 recently. (worst decision of my life, I have never had so many issues with an Android before 13.)

Comment: When you switch to Vibrate mode, does the Do Not Disturb mode also turn on? Otherwise, I'm afraid that both modes and their behaviors are unrelated to each other.

Comment: I know for a fact that prior to Android 13 I could get a call to ring through on Vibrate mode. I am fairly certain that this was accomplished by allowing it through DnD.